# Analysis Service Tabular Cube Refresh Status Check

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

We have an Azure analysis service tabular cube. We are using a WebRequest activity to submit the cube refresh request from a logic app. Is there a way to monitor when the refresh completes so that users can be notified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Azure Data factory web activity to trigger  the cube refresh , wait for the cube to get refreshed and send a mail to the users.

https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/ADFv2/ProcessAzureAS.json

This Open source project link provides the complete JSON for the ADF structure mentioned above.